# Getting stats on system hardware

Tags: operating-system

Now I would like to know how to calculate the load on a computer system. I've heard about load sensors and other utilities which provide the option of finding the temperature of the hard disk or CPU, but I don't want to use them.

All I want to know is the load on CPU, E.G. CPU is 40% free, total usage of memory or amount of free memory, free disk space etc.

I don't need a software tool for finding these things.

I would to know if there is any program in `C` or in any other language or script which can find out these thing one by one or simultaneously?

Are there any commands to find this?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your operating system. On Unix/Linux, there is the directory /proc which contains a lot of files/directories with system information such as /proc/loadvg or /proc/cpuinfo

These aren't real files on your disk, but virtual files containing system information. But you can just open them and read them with standard file functions, so it works with any programming language, from C to Python.

Comment: thanks for help but i want yo know if these file are virtual than where are they stored and how they are created Please explain me are these file keep changing their content as the load on system increase  or can we change them or changing their content effect the system please explain me .

Comment: They live in the RAM / working memory and are created/maintained/updated by the operating system. Some of these files can be changed by the user to change the system's behavior, but of course you can't tell the system to change its load. But yes, they will be updated when the load changes etc.

Comment: cordially sorry for responding late & thanks very much for helping me

Comment: can u tell me which files i can change n how to change them